# Internet Explorer: "Object Expected" error - common causes?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

We recently started using [errorception](http://errorception.com/) to monitor JavaScript errors on [our site](http://www.oyster.com). It's a service that logs client side JavaScript errors.

The vast majority of errors getting reported have been in one of the following two categories:

- "$ is not defined" - presumably because jQuery is not getting loaded because of some network error
- "Object Expected"

I'm trying to figure out where the "Object Expected" error is coming from. It's only getting reported from IE, and it happens across various pages of the site and various versions of IE. I have not been able to reproduce it in a browser, so I was wondering if there is some common mistake or phenomenon that can cause this error.

Comment: To find common causes, I'd recommend searching [\[javascript\] IE Object Expected](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+IE+Object+Expected&submit=search).

Comment: So, this errorception thing doesn't provide additional information about those "Object Expected" errors? (stack, line number, etc.)

Comment: RE: Common causes - I did search that, but all I found were cases that were easily reproducible, which is not the problem I'm having. RE: line numbers - it does provide line numbers, but those are pretty useless for IE if the error is happening in an inline script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object Expected` is the Internet Explorer term for calling an undefined function.

It's because you use jQuery's shorthand `$(function() {})`. In this case the jQuery-object `$` is used as a function.

Reproduced with

```
<script>
    $(function() {});
</script>
```

Comment: When I run that in IE, I'm getting "The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object" in the error console. Where is the "Object Expected" text coming from?

Comment: My example gives me `Object Expected` in IE 8, Windows XP. Are you accessing any `$.foo` before the `$(function() {})` statement ?

Comment: Ah, it must be a difference between IE on XP and IE on Windows 7. The message I gave above was from IE on Windows 7. When I try it on an XP Virtual Machine, I get the "Object Expected" error.